# refer to certain digits and make actions on them in R

Tags: r

how can I make a function that receives a number, 123345,  takes it's 4th and 5th digits and returns this number^2 => i.e 23*23

Do I need to make it with a loop? (so that I can catch numbers that has less than 5 digits, and them complete them to min 5 digits with leading zeros.)

if length(v)<5 ,how to add leading zeros up to 5 digits?
how to make a whole number of 2 digits when referring to v[4] and v[5]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` to append leading 0's (if the number of digits is less than 5), use `substr` to extract the 2nd and 3rd digits, convert to numeric and square it.

```
as.numeric(substr(sprintf("%05d", n1), 2,3))^2
#[1] 529   1 144   0
```

#### data

```
n1 <- c(123345, 143, 1294, 1)
```

Comment: @user3581800  It will append 0's to make it 5 digits (if less than that)

Comment: lets say I want to do the same action 3 times, how do I refer to this argument inside the command?                                        fas<-function(x,n){
      for (i in 1:n){
      y <-c(as.numeric(substr(sprintf("%05d", x), 2,3))^2)
  
      return(y)}
    }

Comment: @user3581800  Did you mean to use `replicate(3, as.numeric(substr(sprintf("%05d", n1), 2,3))^2)`

Comment: is that better than using a for loop?

Comment: @user3581800  `replicate` is also a loop using `sapply`.  So, I don't find much difference.  Or else use `rep` which will be more faster

Comment: this produces a vector with the same replicated number though, I actually meant for it to be applied n times, each time taking last result

Comment: @user3581800  Sorry, I am not entirely sure what you meant

Comment: I want to take the number 1205 apply on it the action above, meaning 20*20 =400 then apply it again on 0400 ----> 40*40=1600 then again ====>60*60..and so on n times. so I made a functions with a loop (above) but I don't know how to make it happen n times

Comment: @user3581800  Why do you need a loop?  I have already showed it without using the loop on a vector of values.  Are you saying that the `%0n` differ in each case?

Comment: no, I am saying that instead of applying the action in question on the last recieved number, I applies it on the same one n times and returns a vector of the same numebr replicated 6 times

Comment: @user3581800  Then wouldn't `rep` works `rep(as.numeric(substr(sprintf("%05d", n1), 2,3))^2, each=5)
# [1] 529 529 529 529 529   1   1   1   1   1 144 144 144 144 144   0   0   0   0   0`